# Setting border radius for date range input and value box R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, widget

I am trying to change the default rectangle shape of the widgets in my app, so the edges are curved. I have looked through other questions and have managed to do this for the selectizeInput, but can't seem to do it for selectDateRange and value box.

In particular, the below works for selectizeInput but not the other two:

```
tags$style(".small-box {border-radius: 50px}"),
tags$style(".selectize-input {border-radius: 50px}"),
tags$style(".input-daterange {border-radius: 50px}"),
```

I add a full reprex below

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
library(corrr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


dataset<-iris%>%
mutate(week=seq(from=as.Date("2017-03-12"), to=as.Date("2020-01-22"), by = "weeks"))


ui <- fluidPage(

tags$style('.container-fluid {
background-color: Lavender;
}'),
tags$style(".small-box.bg-yellow { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; color: #000000 !important;
           border-radius:50px !important:}"),
# tags$li(div(img(src = 'MMix.png', height = "75px"),tile="AAAAA",
# style = "margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:-50px; padding-right:-100px;"),
# class = "dropdown"),
tags$style(".small-box {border-radius: 50px}"),
#tags$style(".selectize-input {border-radius: 50px}"),
tags$style(".input-daterange {border-radius: 50px}"),
fluidRow(column(1,align='right',offset=7,
                tags$style("
              .small-box {
                border-radius: 50px !important;
                border: none;
              }"),
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {height:50px}"))),
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {width: 0px}"))),
div(valueBoxOutput("vbox"),style="color:green;",
style="border-radius:50px"),style="background-color:#6724C6;",
style = "border-style: solid"),
column(4,align='right',style = "border-radius:50px;",
       dateRangeInput("week", "Week",width="400",
end="2020-01-22", start="2017-03-12"))),
fluidRow(
column(4,
selectInput("variable1", "Variable 1:",selected="Petal.Length",
choices=names(dataset[1:4]))),
column(4,
selectInput("variable2", "Variable 2:",selected="Sepal.Length",
choices=names(dataset[1:4]))),
column(4,
selectInput("variable3", "Variable 3:",selected="Species",
choices=names(dataset[5])))),
mainPanel(width=12,
plotOutput("distPlot"),
dataTableOutput("txt"),
verbatimTextOutput("write"),
),
fluidRow(column(12,textInput("caption","Caption","Data Summary"))))


server <- function(input, output) {

output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
valueBox(

value = tags$p( round(cor(q()[,input$variable1],
q()[,input$variable2]),2), style = "font-size: 100%;"),
subtitle = NULL
#   color="navy","R",

)  
})

q<- reactive({
dataset%>%
filter(week>= min(input$week)&
week<=max(input$week))
})


output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
print(ggplot(q(),aes_string(input$variable1, input$variable2))+geom_smooth())

})
output$txt<-renderDataTable({
datatable(
q()[,c(input$variable1,input$variable2)],
options = list(
scrollX = TRUE,
scrollY = "250px"
)        
)
})
output$write <- renderText({ input$caption })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify elements inside of an input (or any other Shiny element), you need to identify the CSS div or class you want to alter. To do so, you can use the navigator inspector on your shiny app (CTRL+SHIFT+I or right click -> inspect), and search the HTML and CSS code to find your element. Then, you can try several modifications directly in the inspector, and copy paste them into your shiny code.

If you want to alter all of the inputs of your page, you can alter the CSS of the class of your object. If you want to alter only one, you need to alter the CSS id of your object. Most of the time in Shiny, it is the inputId.

So in the case, I want to alter the border radius of a `valueBox`. My `valueBox` id is `vbox`, I search in the HTML what is its children element to alter to change the border radius. It is the class `small-box`, so I change the `border-radius` of `#vbox .small-box` in the code.

For the date input it is a bit more tricky, because if you alter the border radius of `form-control` (which is the class name of the element to alter), you will alter both left and right sides. See how it looks on `week1`.

So you should alter only the left side of the first `form-control`, and only the right side of the right `form-control`. See how it looks on `week2`. It is way easier to do your CSS modifications directly in the inspector of the browser, and then copy paste them in your R code.

By the way, when asking a question here it is good to provide a MINIMUM reproducible example, and not too much code. See the code below which is way enough.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
      .selectize-input {border-radius: 50px;}    
      #vbox .small-box {border-radius: 50px;} 
      #week1 .form-control{border-radius: 50px;}
      #week2 > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1) {border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;}
      #week2 > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(3) {border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;}
      "
      )),
    dateRangeInput("week1", "Week",width="400",
                   end="2020-01-22", start="2017-03-12"),
    dateRangeInput("week2", "Week",width="400",
                   end="2020-01-22", start="2017-03-12"),
    selectInput("variable1", "Variable 1:", selected="a",
                choices=c('a','b')),
    valueBoxOutput("vbox")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "80%", "Approval", icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "yellow"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```